# The input line is too long

Tags: cmd.exe

```
curl --request POST --url https://ship.amazon.in/swaapi/v2/some_id/shipments --header 'cache-control: no-cache' --header 'content-type: application/json' --header 'x-swa-token: Atc|MQEBIKSFsFpAwAZc6hHjeAAPfqdgFxhfSD5vIGW34BJG4nUaHayUtfxBkj_ssIs_46_NhW8QvCbpNha1wgZFBYmrfhCzocI4S7bs5XKi6FUE14wI_aHeVVGAItVkAOlkSJ7C29SXh2iIdcfDWrUv6lRwqY8DIH2BCLkr2N0XNcw8Ecxz-yrM5CeDr5bbYFN06TMRKH8KSumL625kOWfhoTClHuVosne-55ucG9BSOL62EoqMUsHeqKGkmR6G8L2XQRkL4yipUOqGtlT1OiOppf6o8svFJVnuJj9eOLbKGl4HdKVpoA' --data'{"transaction":{"transactionIdentifier":"1234"},"shipmentRequest":{"destination":{"address":{"mailingAddress":{"countryCode":"IN","postalCode":"110034","city":"Surat","addressLine1":"Marutidham","attentionName":"MeghaRajpara"}}},"containers":[{"value":{"value":100,"unit":"INR"},"valueAddedServiceProperties":{"collectOnDeliveryProperties":{"containerCODAmount":{"unit":"INR","value":450},"itemLevelCODAmounts":[{"itemId":"ITEM-1","amount":{"unit":"INR","value":2300}}]}},"identifiers":{"clientRefId":"43f65667-921b-4822-a346-d4c8ac886789","containerReferenceId":"7df1c643-be34-45b7-aac4-04faaad7dc3f"},"physicalAttributes":{"height":{"unit":"CM","value":10},"length":{"unit":"CM","value":10},"width":{"unit":"CM","value":5},"weight":{"unit":"G","value":50}},"itemInfo":[{"unitPrice":{"value":100,"unit":"INR"}}]}],"expectedServiceOffering":{"expectedPromise":{"receiveWindow":{"dateTimeRange":{"start":"2017-04-23T05:05:24.094Z"}}}},"clientReferenceId":"a1a924a3-7cbe-44b1-9a91-f09c1879011f","origin":{"address":{"mailingAddress":{"countryCode":"IN","postalCode":"395006","city":"Surat","addressLine1":"Marutidham","attentionName":"MeghaRajpara"}}},"shippingPurpose":"SALE"}}'
```

The above command give me the following error:

> The input line is too long.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is **not** about line too long, because your command has only 1673 characters, and the limit is [8191 characters for commands entering into `cmd.exe`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=41553)

> On computers running Microsoft Windows XP or later, the maximum length of the string that you can use at the command prompt is 8191 characters. On computers running Microsoft Windows 2000 or Windows NT 4.0, the maximum length of the string that you can use at the command prompt is 2047 characters.

> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd.-exe-command-line-string-limitation

Now look at your command

```
curl ... --header 'cache-control: no-cache' --header 'content-type: application/json'
--header 'x-swa-token: Atc|MQEBIKSFsFpAwAZc6hHjeAAPfqdgFxhfSD5vIGW34BJG4nUaHayUtfxBkj
_ssIs_46_NhW8QvCbpNha1wgZFBYmrfhCzocI4S7bs5XKi6FUE14wI
_aHeVVGAItVkAOlkSJ7C29SXh2iIdcfDWrUv6lRwqY8DIH2BCLkr2N0XNcw8Ecxz
-yrM5CeDr5bbYFN06TMRKH8KSumL625kOWfhoTClHuVosne-55ucG9BSOL62EoqMU
sHeqKGkmR6G8L2XQRkL4yipUOqGtlT1OiOppf6o8svFJVnuJj9eOLbKGl4HdKVpoA...'
```

[Single quote `'` is not a quoting symbol in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24173825/995714), so unlike what one might expect `'cache-control: no-cache'` will be passed as **2 separate parameters**: `'cache-control:` and `no-cache'`

As a result, in `'x-swa-token: Atc|MQEBIKSFsFpAwAZc6hHjeAAPfqd...` the `'x-swa-token: Atc` part will be recognized as the last 2 parameters of the first command, whose output will be piped into a command called `MQEBIKSFsFpAwAZc6hHjeAAPfqd...` which probably doesn't exist

You need to change single quotes to double quotes. However as you're using nested double quotes inside the strings, doing that would be a pain

---

Nevertheless there are various solutions. [In PowerShell `'` can be used to quote strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1), so you can just avoid the obsolete cmd.exe altogether and use PowerShell with the above command *as-is*. Newer Windows 10 also deprecates cmd.exe and use PowerShell by default.

Anyway in PowerShell there's already [`net.webclient.DownloadString`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35818093/995714) so you may use it directly, eliminating the need for `curl`

Since build 17063 onwards [`curl` is also built into Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20171219-tar-and-curl-come-to-windows) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221043708/https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2017/12/19/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/)) and you can use it directly